# REGEXP match either keywords in the string using MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I am trying to search for a keyword in the string using REGEXP, how I want to search is:

Stored String 1: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
Stored String 2: "The clever rabbit ran away from the tiger"
Keywords: "Clever| Fox"  (The two keywords separated by the delimiter "|")

I want to search for a stories which contains the either one of the keywords or all of the keywords.

I used str_replace the keyword string to make a keyword string a regular expression that can be used in mysql query. I tried many solutions which are provided here to previously asked questions but I found nothing working for me.

One of what I have tried so far is this:

```
SELECT * FROM stories WHERE story_body REGEXP '[[:<:]]Clever[[:>:]].*[[:<:]] Fox[[:>:]]'
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^.*(Clever|Fox).*$
```

Simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/55

or

```
^.*\b(Clever|Fox)\b.*$
```

Just to be very safe.

Comment: you are great this worked like a charm. Thanks!! one thing where do I learn this regex are there any video tuts or a good resource?

Comment: @Iglance3 regex101.com .... you can learn here......check explanation at right side....only practice can make you aficionado in regex.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you, but It doesn't work with multiple keywords.. If there is a third keyword or more then it will not work...

Comment: ok I got my issue in my example I forgot the / /gim, thanks again

Comment: It doesn't match two different keywords or even the same keywords on the same line it matches the last on that line. see https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/72

Comment: But it is now not matching the second keyword that is "sleeping" on the second line.

Comment: I mean to say it should match both of the keywords in the same line for eg, in the second line there are two keywords which I want to search and these are "clever" and another is "sleeping" so it should highlight both

Comment: @Iglance3 that is not possible .Regex engine once matches moves out of alternation group.that will require you to build  a specific regex for this.But it wont be generic.See https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/74